# Strengthened Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f(.)$ be a non-negative integrable function on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu).$ Prove that :
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} t\ \mu(\{x: f(x) \geq t\}) =0
$$

We know by Chebyshev's inequality that:
$$
\mu(\{x:f(x) \geq t\}) \leq \frac{\int f \ d\mu}{t}
$$
How can I prove the above ? We don't know if $\int f^2(x) \ d\mu < \infty.$ In that case, it's very easy to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let

$$g(t)=\mu(\{ x : f(x) \geq t \}).$$

Then

$$\int_0^\infty g(t) dt = \int_X f d \mu.$$

So $g$ is a decreasing, nonnegative, integrable function. If $g$ were continuous, how would you prove that $\lim_{t \to \infty} t g(t)=0$? Can you adapt that proof to deal with the more general case? (It may help to recall some properties of monotone functions.)

Comment: The idea is elegant but I couldn't prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)dt= \int_{X}f d\mu.$ Should we use Fubini's theorem or sth ?

Comment: Fubini is a way, but you can also work directly. There is a nice picture of adding up lengths of horizontal rectangles instead of vertical ones as in Riemann integration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to the proof of @Ian: For $t >0$, consider $f_t := f \cdot 1_{f \geq t} $. It is not hard to see $f_{t_n} \to 0$ a.e. for every sequence $t_n\to \infty $. In fact, this convergence is true everywhere if $f (x)<\infty $ for all $x $.

Now use that $f_{t_n} $ is dominated by the integrable $f $, so that
$$
t_n \cdot \mu (\{f \geq t_n\}) \leq \int f_{t_n}\,d\mu \to 0
$$
by dominated convergence.